# lapply to left_join list of datasets

Tags: r, for-loop, left-join, lapply

I got two lists of datasets that I want to `left_join`. They are ordered, so the first dataset on the `list1` should be joined with the first dataset on `list2`, the second one on `list1` with the second on `list2` and so on. I've been trying to do this with `lapply`, but I get the following error message:

[image]

Here is some sample data:

```
set.seed(1234)

n1 <- LETTERS[1:10]
x1 <- rnorm(10,1) 
y1 <- rnorm(10,2)
z1 <- rnorm(10,3)

n2 <- LETTERS[5:14]
x2 <- rnorm(10,1) 
y2 <- rnorm(10,2)
z2 <- rnorm(10,3)

df1 <- data.frame(n1,x1,y1,z1)  
df2 <- data.frame(n2,x2,y2,z2)  
list1 <- list(df1, df2)

n1 <- LETTERS[5:14]
x3 <- rnorm(10,2) 
y3 <- rnorm(10,3)
z3 <- rnorm(10,4)

n2 <- LETTERS[1:10]
x4 <- rnorm(10,2) 
y4 <- rnorm(10,3)
z4 <- rnorm(10,4)

df3 <- data.frame(n1,x3,y3,z3)  
df4 <- data.frame(n2,x4,y4,z4)  
list2 <- list(df3, df4)
```

And here is the code that I'm trying to make work:

```
lapply(list1, function(x) left_join(x, list2[[x]]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `Map` here :

```
Map(dplyr::left_join, list1, list2)
```

To use `lapply`, you could loop over the index.

```
lapply(seq_along(list1), function(x) dplyr::left_join(list1[[x]], list2[[x]]))
```

Comment: Thanks! If I were to use `map`, where do I put the arguments of the variables to `left_join`? (say, `by = c("variable1", "variable2"`)

Comment: `map2(list1, list2, left_join, by = c("variable1", "variable2"))` Or with `map`, `map(seq_along(list1), ~left_join(list1[[.x]], list2[[.x]], by = c("variable1", "variable2")))`

Answer (score 3):

Using `purrr`, you can do:

```
map2(.x = list1, 
     .y = list2, 
     ~ left_join(.x, .y))

[[1]]
   n1         x1       y1       z1       x3       y3       z3
1   A -0.2070657 1.522807 3.134088       NA       NA       NA
2   B  1.2774292 1.001614 2.509314       NA       NA       NA
3   C  2.0844412 1.223746 2.559452       NA       NA       NA
4   D -1.3456977 2.064459 3.459589       NA       NA       NA
5   E  1.4291247 2.959494 2.306280 2.656588 3.006893 3.822210
6   F  1.5060559 1.889715 1.551795 4.548991 2.544531 3.830006
7   G  0.4252600 1.488990 3.574756 1.965240 2.633476 2.627698
8   H  0.4533681 1.088805 1.976344 1.330366 3.648287 3.826213
9   I  0.4355480 1.162828 2.984862 1.992395 5.070271 4.850232
10  J  0.1099622 4.415835 2.064051 3.777084 2.846602 4.697609

[[2]]
   n2         x2        y2       z2       x4       y4       z4
1   E  2.1022975 3.4494963 1.193969 1.504417 2.174001 4.022363
2   F  0.5244069 0.9313573 2.417924 2.355550 3.166989 4.831141
3   G  0.2905600 1.1446354 1.891110 0.865392 2.103735 2.755712
4   H  0.4987419 1.7193770 1.985038 2.878204 3.168185 4.169026
5   I -0.6290935 1.0056599 2.837690 2.972917 3.354968 4.673166
6   J -0.1676193 1.0314857 3.563056 4.121117 2.947895 3.973724
7   K -1.1800396 0.8926818 4.647817       NA       NA       NA
8   L -0.3409932 0.7480141 2.226647       NA       NA       NA
9   M  0.7057061 1.4761719 4.605910       NA       NA       NA
10  N  0.5341025 1.5031500 1.842191       NA       NA       NA
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `mapply` instead of `lapply`:

```
mapply(left_join, list1, list2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```